# With web scrapers, is it better to scrape all data and filter the variables internally, or pre-filter?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to set up a system whereby users can be notified of news from various organizations (using Twitter as an easy delivery mechanism). The issue I'm having is how to compile the data cleanly, whether to have multiple web scrapers running the different topics or one giant scraper that a user can then filter through via buttons or some other toggle-able setting. Would the latter be too complicated?

I have not tried anything as of yet besides running through a basic webscraping tutorial.

No code currently exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think one program should only focus on only one problem at a time, so here is some of my thought.

You can run one scraper service that crawls and updates articles of all news sites daily, don't need to worry about topic classification at this stage. All articles can share one data structure, like:

```
# You can leave the topic field or give it null.
_id, post_ts, title, content, topic, url
```

For the classification part, you can then make a classification service that classifies each new article into different categories, update the `topic` field in the database and make use of `post_ts` field, so you can do it incrementally.